# Convert Array[DenseVector] to CSV with Scala

Tags: scala, csv, cluster-computing, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I am using Kmeans Spark function with Scala and I need to save the Cluster Centers obtained into a CSV. This val is type: `Array[DenseVector]`.

```
val clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, numClusters, numIterations)
val centers = clusters.clusterCenters
```

I was trying converting `centers` to a RDD file and then from RDD to DF, but I get a lot of problems (e.g, import spark.implicits._ / SQLContext.implicits._ is not working and I cannot use `.toDF`). I was wondering if there is another way to make a CSV easier.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without use of external libraries you can do that by simply writing to the file Java way.

```
import java.io.{ PrintWriter, File, FileOutputStream }

...

val pw = new PrintWriter(
    new File( "KMeans_centers.csv" )
)

centers
.foreach( vec =>
        pw.write( vec.toString.drop( 1 ).dropRight( 1 ) + "\n" )
    )

pw.close()
```

Resulting file

```
0.1,0.1,0.1
9.1,9.1,9.1
```

`drop` and `dropRight` are needed to remove `[]` around the converted vector.

Code and data are taken from the official [example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-clustering.html#k-means).