# Perfomance of coalesce(1).limt(100000)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large volume of logs (about 15 Tb) on disk.
I run full-scan to search, and I want to return the first 100,000 rows, that match to condition, write result to csv and drop the search. I use  code below (I understand that coalesce(1) is not very good, but I haven't found any other options so far).

When I call a function for writing csv, a temporary folder appears on  disk  immediately with the csv partition, that contains almost all the results except small amount of rows. And time for appearing remaining rows in csv is rather big.

When I collect dataframe to driver node, collecting is working very fast, and writing csv from driver node is also fast.

Why is such different behavior for collect() and write.csv()?

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("/mnt/testapache/*/raw_logs")
val df2 = df.filter("""_raw like '%GET%'""").coalesce(1).limit(100000)
df2.write.csv("/mnt/csv/result") // this works slow
val res = df2.collect() // this works fast
writecsv(res) // Custom function for write csv
```

Output of csv in temp folder(last line is not finalized) with test logs:

```
nl *.csv | tail -n 2

99908   "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X 10_6_7 rv:4.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/535.23.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0 Safari/535.23.1",http://www.internationalintegrate.biz/e-commerce/b2c/systems/eyeballs,GET /web-enabled/maximize/cross-platform/portals,"127.174.73.95 - hills6078 [02/05/2019:01:11:32 +0000] \"GET /web-enabled/maximize/cross-platform/portals\" 304 27318 \"http://www.internationalintegrate.biz/e-commerce/b2c/systems/eyeballs\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X 10_6_7 rv:4.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/535.23.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0 Safari/535.23.1\"",defaultHost,127.174.73.95,304,defaultSourcetype,defaultSource,02/05/2019:01:11:32 +0000,1556759492000,27318
99909   "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_3_2 like Mac OS X;en-US) AppleWebKit/536.44.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0.5Mobile/8B111 Safari/6536.44.6",https://www.nationaltransparent.org/seamless/facilitate,GET /deliver/exploit/global,"148.205.50.165 - - [02/05/2019:01:01:54 +0000] \"GET /deliver/exploit/g
```

Comment: By first 100000 lines, you mean in the order of the file ? Or whatever lines ?

Comment: I search "GET" in logs for example, i want to output 100000 rows to csv, that contains "GET", order is not important

Comment: Can you show us the code of your custom writecsv ? Hav you tried without the coalesce 1? The colesce do not mean you will have only one partition each time

Comment: Have you tried change order, "limit" and then "coalesce"?

Comment: Yes, i tried different variants, i found that collect works fast without coalesce(1), just with limit. writecsv  is function like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086945/convert-arraydensevector-to-csv-with-scala

Comment: Why do you colaesce then? I mean it is mandatory ? Because it can drastically increase the computation Time (also, this is very differe't from repartition)

Comment: As far as I understand, the limit is worked on all the  partitions , and it is necessary to wait until partitions work out. Using coalesce(1) I try to make only one partitions and make "limit" work faster. I am confused that with coalesce(1).limit(n) almost all the data appears in csv at once, and the rest of the time is spent on outputting a very small part of the data.